# SELECT biggest row from a LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

I have a SQL query that LEFT JOINs a table into it.  This causes rows from the main table to be duplicated but with different rows from the JOINed table.  How do I only select the rows with the highest date from the JOINed table.

Here's an example (this is the result from my query):

```
ID    Message    Date
---------------------------
0     Hi         2011-01-01
0     Bye        2011-02-05
0     Hello      2011-04-20
1     Test       2010-12-31
1     Testing    2010-11-15
2     Something  2010-12-12
2     Nothing    2011-01-01
2     Yes        2010-02-05
3     Cool       NULL
```

I want one row per ID, the row with the highest ID.

```
ID    Message    Date
---------------------------
0     Hello      2011-04-20
1     Test       2010-12-31
2     Nothing    2011-01-01
3     Cool       NULL
```

My current query is something like this (I just kinda made this up, but it's similar to the real one):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Message, t2.Date
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t3.ID, t3.message, t3.Date
  FROM t3
  LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.userID = 12 AND t3.ID = t4.ID
  WHERE t4.color = 'blue'
) AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.userID = 12
```

I guess I could use PHP and loop through the results and pick out the ones I want, but can I have MySQL do that for me?

**EDIT**: Sorry, my 1st example was *way* wrong, this is more like what I want.

**EDIT 2**: I tried using GROUP BY and MAX, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

I tried:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Message, MAX(t2.Date)
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT t3.ID, t3.message, t3.Date
  FROM t3
  LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.userID = 12 AND t3.ID = t4.ID
  WHERE t4.color = 'blue'
) AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.userID = 12
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

But, that gave me:

```
ID    Message    Date
---------------------------
0     Hi         2011-04-20
1     Test       2010-12-31
2     Something  2011-01-01
3     Cool       NULL
```

How do I get the Message associated with the highest date.

Comment: Inside inner query, put a group by on Id and select max date ....

Comment: It's hard for me to follow the example but it looks like you're along the right lines. Might make for a longer post but could you put together some table structures/sample data?

Comment: @Rocket - Is `t3.Id` the primary key of t3 or is that purely a foreign key to the `t1` table?

Comment: If I am reading this query correctly, so for 0 id in T1 table, we have 3 different messages?

Comment: @Thomas, This may not be the best example...  But as you can see t3 (aliased to t2) is JOINed to t1 on ID.

Comment: @Rocket - Yes, but it is not intuitive that a column called `ID` is a foreign key and not a primary key. My first thought with that scenario is that there is a 1:1 relationship between `t1` and `t3` as opposed to a 1:Many.

Comment: @Rocket - Let me put it this way, if `t3.Id` is the primary key of `t3`, that changes the solution dramatically.

Comment: @Thomas: Check the question now, I totally wrote it wrong, the example is more like how I want it now.

Comment: @Rocket - Ok. I've revised my post. However, my question about `t3.id` still remains. Is `t3.id` the PK of the `t3` table?

Comment: @Thomas: No, t3.id is not the primary key.  It's 1:many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT 
   t1.ID, 
   t1.Message, 
   MAX(t2.Date) as [Date]
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT t3.ID, t3.Date
    FROM t3
    LEFT JOIN t4 ON t4.userID = 12 AND t3.ID = t4.ID
    WHERE t3.color = 'blue'
 ) AS t2
 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
 WHERE t1.userID = 12
 GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.Message
```

You can use `GROUP BY` to group on certain values with the restriction that you have to group on all the values in the *select list*, unless it is an *aggregate function*, like `MAX`.

Comment: Thanks, this actually works, but I realized that my question was wrong.  I fixed my example, so this no longer works.

Comment: I actually managed to solve it by using GROUP BYs and an ORDER BY in the subquery

Answer (score 4):

```
Select t1.id, t1.Message, t3.date
From t1
    Left Join t3
        On t3.id = t1.id
            And t3.id = (
                        Select Max( t3_1.Id )
                        From t3 As t3_1
                        Where t3_1.id = t3.id
                        Having Max( t3_1.date ) = t3.date
                        )
Where t1.userID = 12
```

As far as I can tell, the join to `t4` plays no part in the query whatsoever. It doesn't filter the results nor is anything from the `t4` table displayed in the Select clause. In addition, I have assumed that the column `t3.id` is actually a foreign key to the `t1` table and not the primary key. If it is the primary key, then the other filter for max date is not necessary.

---

**Update given question revision**

By adding criteria to the Where clause on `t4`, you have effectively converted it to an inner join. Still, one solution is:

```
Select t1.id, t3.Message, t3.date
From t1
    Left Join t3
        On t3.id = t1.id
            And t3.id = (
                        Select Max( t3_1.Id )
                        From t3 As t3_1
                            Join t4
                                On t4.id = t3_1.id
                        Where t4.color = 'blue'
                            And t3_1.id = t3.id
                        Having Max( t3_1.date ) = t3.date
                        )
Where t1.userID = 12
```

Comment: Check the question now, I totally wrote it wrong, the example is more like how I want it now.