# mysql left join selecting only highest from left table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I've tried adapting solutions from [SELECT biggest row from a LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794865/select-biggest-row-from-a-left-join) and [mysql: How to INNER JOIN a table but limit join to 1 result with the highest vote or count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425894/mysql-how-to-inner-join-a-table-but-limit-join-to-1-result-with-the-highest-vot?rq=1) but can't figure it out.

I'm joining two tables, the one being joined has two duplicate rows, the only difference is field 'page_id' - I want the one with the highest page_id number

```
tagID  page_id  companyID  teamID  companyID
1510   289      16         9       16
1418   163      16         9       16
```

(there are other text fields I want but these aren't used in matching so excluded them here)

My original query was

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_company_tags` 
LEFT JOIN `cms_companies` ON `cms_companies`.`companyID`=`cms_company_tags`.`companyID` 
WHERE `cms_company_tags`.`teamID`='9'
ORDER BY `cms_companies`.`companyName` ASC
```

which selected both rows

```
tagID  page_id  companyID  teamID  newsID  companyID
1510   289      16         9       0       16
1418   163      16         9       0       16
```

I've tried

```
Select cms_company_tags.*, cms_companies.*
From cms_company_tags
    Left Join cms_companies
        On cms_companies.companyID = cms_company_tags.companyID
            And cms_companies.page_id = (
                        Select Max( t.page_id )
                        From cms_companies As t
                        Where t.page_id = cms_company_tags.page_id
                GROUP BY cms_company_tags.tagID
                ORDER BY cms_company_tags.tagID DESC 
                        )
WHERE `cms_company_tags`.`teamID`='9'
ORDER BY `cms_companies`.`companyName` ASC
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `cms_company_tags` 
LEFT JOIN `cms_companies` ON `cms_companies`.`companyID`=`cms_company_tags`.`companyID` 
AND `cms_companies`.`page_id` = (SELECT MAX(page_id) AS pageID from `cms_companies` where `cms_companies`.`page_id` = `cms_company_tags`.`page_id`)                             
WHERE `cms_company_tags`.`teamID`='9'
ORDER BY `cms_companies`.`companyName` ASC
```

Both of which return

```
tagID  page_id  companyID  teamID  newsID  companyID
1510   289      16         9       0       NULL
1418   163      16         9       0       16
```

With all the text fields being NULL too

I want the only the highest page_id. I could live with a duplicate row with NULL for the text field if it were the highest one and not the lowest one as I'm getting how.

---

EDIT:

Although this solution from returns the LOWEST page_id it does filter out the duplicate, luckily for me the text parts I need weren't affected. Posting here in the hope this partial solution is useful to someone

SELECT *
FROM cms_company_tags
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT companyID, companyName, page_path, MAX(page_id) AS MaxPageID
  FROM cms_companies
  GROUP BY cms_companies.page_id
) MaxPages ON
  cms_company_tags.companyID = MaxPages.companyID AND
  cms_company_tags.page_id = MaxPages.MaxPageID AND
cms_company_tags.teamID = 9 
ORDER BY MaxPages.`companyName` ASC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: why are you joining? You're only selecting from the left table, so left joining to another table won't affect the results. An inner join would affect results (by omitting companies that don't exist in `cms_companies`), but a left join won't.

At any rate, to get the highest page ID by company ID and team ID, try this:

```
SELECT companyID, teamID, MAX(page_ID)
FROM cms_company_tags
GROUP BY companyID, teamID
```

Then to get the unique rows from `cms_company_tags`, just join to the "highest by ID" as a subquery:

```
SELECT tagID, page_id, companyID, teamID
FROM cms_company_tags
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT companyID, teamID, MAX(page_ID) AS MaxPageID
  FROM cms_company_tags
  GROUP BY companyID, teamID
) MaxPages ON
  cms_company_tags.companyID = MaxPages.companyID AND
  cms_company_tags.teamID = MaxPages.teamID
  cms_company_tags.page_id = MaxPages.MaxPageID
```

This query returns the max page and other information for all companies/teams. You can add `WHERE teamID = 9` to limit results to team 9.

Comment: Really close, this... SELECT * FROM cms_company_tags INNER JOIN ( SELECT companyID, companyName, MAX(page_ID) AS MaxPageID FROM cms_companies GROUP BY cms_companies.companyID ) MaxPages ON cms_company_tags.companyID = MaxPages.companyID AND cms_company_tags.page_id = MaxPages.MaxPageID AND cms_company_tags.teamID = 9 ... works but still selects the lowest page_id ???

Comment: Tweaked your code, returns lowest page_id but luckily the text field I need to extract is the same for both so works in my particular case.... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you used ROW_NUMBER windowed function in sql server. 
May be what you are looking is this:

```
select * from(
select *,row_number()over(partition by companyid, teamid, newsid, companyid order by page_id desc) as num
from 'cms_company_tags'
left join 'cms_companies' on 'cms_companies'.'companyID'='cms_company_tags'.'companyID'
where 'cms_company_tags'.'teamID'='9'
)tbl
where tbl.num =1
```